# Ruby SQS Parsing Message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Initially I sent the converted object using .to_json which gives me a string I sent this to sqs. Now i'm retrieving the message and now it's in string form? How do I parse it back into my inital object?

--Edit

Ruby on Rails. I'm using a library to contact sqs and send the object over. Before I send it, I convert it using .to_json. Then Now, I'm writing a backend.rb file that uses that library and receives the msg and if there is a msg i want it to convert that msg back into a @project then I plan to send this @project over to a template .erb file.

Comment: Is this Ruby on Rails, and is this a website, and are you using a library like jQuery for your client-side JavaScript? Or is this pure Ruby?

Comment: Parsing a JSON string is going to give you simple Ruby objects like Hash, Array, String, etc. It sounds like `@project` may be a model instance from an ActiveRecord-backed database. Is your view expecting a model, or is it fine to directly access properties of (for example) a Hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a JSON string into Ruby objects, call `JSON.parse` like so:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse( '{"foo":"bar"}' )
#=> {"foo"=>"bar"}

a = JSON.parse( '[1,2,3] )
#=> [1, 2, 3]

JSON.parse( '{"name":"Gavin","cats":["Phleep","Tessa"]}' )
#=> {"name"=>"Gavin", "cats"=>["Phleep", "Tessa"]}
```